# Order by an Aliased Column is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am attempting to Order by an Aliased Column without any luck.

The tables:

Movie ( mID, title, year, director ) 
English: There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

Reviewer ( rID, name ) 
English: The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
English: The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

The homework question is:

For each movie, return the title and the 'rating spread', that is, the difference between highest and lowest ratings given to that movie. Sort by rating spread from highest to lowest, then by movie title.

I've tried this query a few ways with no luck.

```
SELECT Movie.Title, (MAX(Rating.stars) - MIN(Rating.stars)) AS Spread
FROM Movie
JOIN Rating ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
GROUP BY Rating.mID
ORDER BY Movie.Title
ORDER BY Spread
```

I expect the output below:

```
MOVIE | SPREAD
Avatar | 2
Gone with the Wind | 2
Raiders of the Lost Ark | 2
E.T. | 1
Snow White | 1
The Sound of Music | 1
```

but the actual output is Query failed to execute: near 'ORDER': syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is expecting 1 `ORDER BY` clause, you need to add the second `ORDER BY` to the first with comma.

```
ORDER BY Movie.Title, Spread
```

`ORDER BY` with an aliased column is working, because in all RDBMS the `ORDER BY` clause is executed after the `SELECT`

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY Spread DESC, Movie.Title  ;

Comment: Add ``` before and after the code to format it properly. Also please add some explanation too